# How to write the constraints in CVX not using a loop

Tags: matlab, optimization, cvx

I'm using the matlab package "CVX" to solve an optimization problem. Currently I'm using a for loop to add the constraints, but I found that it is extremely slow when initializing the problem.

```
for i=1:n
    norm(Nout(i,:)-Nin(i,:))<=tau;
end
```

**Nout** and **Nin** is two matrix of size n*3, and I need the norm of each row of the matrix **Nout-Nin** is smaller than a threshold, how could I write this without loops? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the norm manually:

```
result = sqrt(sum((Nout - Nin) .^ 2, 2)) <= tau
```